# How to Solve tools:replace erorr in Xamarin.forms App

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-manifest

My Xamarin.Forms app when is in debug work perfectly fine, no errors also connect on my device and everything is ok. But when i change to `Release|Any CPU` and try to archive i get this 4 errors:

1`tools:replace specified at line:15 for attribute android:icon, but no new value specified`

2.`D:\MyApp\MyApp.Android\obj\Release\100\AndroidManifest.xml:15:3-43:17 Error:`
3. `Validation failed`

4.`D:\MyApp\MyApp.Android\obj\Release\100\AndroidManifest.xml Error:`

I don't what should make this problem .I have added : `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` and in `<application>` tag added this : `tools:replace="android:label , android:icon"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it , for new android u must add `android:icon="@mipmap/icon"`